# NVIDIA GeForce 210 - taking out on-board network on HP ProLiant ML150G6?

Tags: networking, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, hp-proliant

I have fairly new HP server: ProLiant ML150G6. On board video only supports low resolutions. Installed NVIDIA GeForce 210 (required a DVI-VGA adapter for my ViewSonic monitor).

Card works great, but since I installed the card, the onboard networking has stopped functioning: Tried with two different cables, verified as working, and booted both to Windows 2003 server and Ubuntu 12.04 - always the same result: "network disconnected" although the green light in the machine and the light on the router indicate that there is a physical connection. Seems the video card has created a problem with the onboard networking.

What's wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: If you take the network cable out of the server and plug it into another computer, what does it say?

Comment: @mxl_ - appreciated, but please read the question carefully before commenting. :-)

Comment: I did. I was suggesting you test another machine on the same connection; your question does not make it unequivocally clear that you have, just that you have tested the cables and that the connection worked before on the server.

Comment: This is a bit of a stretch as an explanation, but here's the theory: the specs (http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/ds_00148/ds_00148.pdf) say the network is "Embedded HP NC107i PCI Express Gigabit Server Adapter"...some motherboards share PCIe lanes...when you plug in a GPU it turns off the lane doing the networking. I'd need to know a lot more about the motherboard architecture to know if this is even plausible though.

Comment: @Ash - I don't think it's that much of a stretch. That's the sort of thing I smell. When it happened, it reminded me of the IRQ conflicts of ancient times... :-)

Comment: @mxl_ - maybe I wasn't clear enough but I did say "verified as working" - I meant with other machines on the same network with the same router. But let us not quibble. I appreciate your attempt to help, but I'm quite sure this is not a cable issue.

Comment: @Ash - I'm thinking I should buy NIC and plug it into another slot instead of using the onBoard. Think that would help? Is it because of that slot, or does the network just get cut out? How can a **server** do such a thing? I should send it back to HP and demand a refund!

Comment: @Vector: Is there another slot you can try the GPU in? I've really got no idea how to fix it, sorry -- was just supposition.

Comment: I didn't state it was a cable issue either. Did you pursue this further? Just curious.